# Mutual fund question; what is a 'Series'?

Tags: mutual-funds, terminology

In mutual fund lingo, what is a 'Series'?  What does it mean?

Comment: I think you mean "share class". If you do, say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really just mean a *family* of funds.

They may share the same investment style or manager or some other definable characteristic.

A large fund company or bank may have several *kinds* of funds.  Some targeting growth, others dividends, etc.  Series is a shorthand for marketing and other purposes.

Comment: This isn't correct. There is a difference between a family of funds and a series (or rather, classes). The other response http://money.stackexchange.com/a/6940/3361 correctly answers the question.

Answer (score 9):

This can also refer to different classes of the same identical but with different fee structures.

E.g.

- Class A-  2% front Load
- Class B - No front load but with 1% redemption fee
- Class C - no load but with 12b-1 fees

http://www.investopedia.com/articles/mutualfund/05/shareclass.asp